# Solr query sdouble field for not null

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I have a field from type sdouble which can be null / non existing if not filled up. I want to only get items that have this field filled up and tried with "-fieldname:null" but I get an exceiption:

```
[msg] => For input string: "null"
[trace] => java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

As the default in jave for most numeric datatypes is 0, I tried with `-fieldname:0` but then got all items back. Anyone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range queries are a good way to check for *any* value.

Try `fieldname:[* TO *]`. You could use actual numbers in the place of the `*`s, but shouldn't have to. The only records that should not match the range of `[* TO *]` are the ones with no value at all for the field.